# Python ''PRAW'' api library crashes script

Tags: python, api, praw

I have been working on a python script intended to help moderate a subreddi using 'warnings'. However, i am unable to get it to work,as when i get to the point in the script where it it supposed to utilise the api, the python window just closes. I have tried using more simple scripts,but non of them work. Here is my simpler file(i used it for testing):

```
import prawcore
import praw
from os.path import isfile
import praw
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
# Get credentials from DEFAULT instance in praw.ini
reddit = praw.Reddit()
# begining of script
#login
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='this is where i put my user agent',
                     client_secret='this is where i put my secret',
                     password='this is wher i put my password',
                     user_agent='PARS (Python-based Advanced Reddit Reprimand System) by u/veryinterestingnut',
                     username='PicoModBot')
print(reddit.user.me())
```

And here is my praw.ini file:

```
# The URL prefix for regular requests.
reddit_url=https://www.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for short URLs.
short_url=https://redd.it

[DEFAULT]
client_id=my id was here
client_secret=this is where i put my pass
user_agent=PARS (Python-based Advanced Reddit Reprimand System) by u/veryinterestingnut
username=PicoModBot
password=my account pass was here
```

What can i do to try and fix this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe this happens on Windows sometimes — when the program completes, the window closes. To fix this, try adding `input("press enter to close")` as the very last line of your script.

Comment: @jarhill0 It didn't help. Thanks for trying to help thought!

Comment: Can you be more specific? When you say "it didn't work," that doesn't give me any information to help figure out the problem. 

If you have a traceback, it would be useful to share. Your Python script seems entirely fine, so I doubt that there's an issue in your code. Are you able to run other python programs successfully?

Comment: @jarhill0 I think it has something to do with the api; whenever i try to use it,the program closes when it gets to the part that actually attempts to uttilize it. No traceback,sorry. And yes,all python scripts without praw run fine

Comment: I missed one thing when reading your script. You initialize `reddit` twice for some reason. Remove the first one, because it isn't doing anything but it is likely causing an exception to be raised.